# I get the following environment-dependent error in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I get the following environment-dependent error in terraform.
What action should I take to resolve it?

```
Error: Post "https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project/locations/asia-northeast1/environments?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": Post "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token": dial tcp 172.217.25.202:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

The error that was output when opening the above url is as follows.

```
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

The terraform code used is as follows.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "auto-expire" {
  name          = "auto-expiring-bucket"
  location      = "US"
}
```

teraform apply without any arguments.

Comment: Post your terraform code that produces this error. Include details on how you are authorizing Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to follow this Terraform doc [adding-credentials](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials) to setup credentials.

Related [access_token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#access_token) [client_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/client_config).

This could also happen if your config is extremely large as those tokens timeout after an hour.